# Leaflet/mapbox popups on markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to grab locations from my database and show them on a map. The markers show up where I need them to, but when I bind my popups to them, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

This is my JS:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([42.351776, -71.061371], 14);

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'TOKEN';
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com//{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=' + L.mapbox.accessToken, {
attribution: '<a href="http://www.mapbox.com/about/maps/" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Feedback</a>'
}).addTo(map);

$.get( '/events.json', function( data ) {
  for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var coordinatesArray =  [data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude];
    `var marker = L.marker([coordinatesArray[0],coordinatesArray[1]]).addTo(map);`

    marker.bindPopup("<h1>" + data.title + "</h1>");
  }
});
```

It seems to work if I just load one marker with a popup, but when I try to iterate through objects, it starts to give me the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to drop the backticks around your marker creation, and also include the current index when accessing `title`.So instead of `data.title`, use `data[i].title`.